Strange behavior of editor-color-palette: colors only showing after re-render of block
I'm experiencing a strange behavior of a block in PluginDocumentSettingPanel. I've registered some colors in editor-color-palette. I want these to be selectable in the document setting panel. Here's the code:
add_action( 'after_setup_theme' , function () {
    add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' , [
        [ 'name' => __( 'White' ) , 'slug' => 'white' , 'color' => '#FFFFFF' ] , 
        /* ... */
    ] );
});

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' , function () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'colorsPanel' , get_template_uri_by_dir( __DIR__ , 'js/editorPlugin.js' ) , [ 'metaComponents' ] );
} );


;( function ( { 
    components : { MetaColorPalette } , 
    data : { useSelect } , 
    editor : { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } , 
    element : { createElement : el } , 
    i18n : { __ } , 
    plugins : { registerPlugin } 
} ) {
    
    registerPlugin( 'post-colors' , { 
        icon : null , 
        render : () => { 
            const colors = useSelect( 'core/block-editor' ).getSettings().colors;
            console.log( colors );
            return el( PluginDocumentSettingPanel , { name : 'postColors' , title : __( 'Colors' ) , initialOpen : true } , 
                el( 'p' , null , __( 'Foreground' ) ) , 
                el( MetaColorPalette , { metaKey : 'foregroundColor' , useSlug : true , colors : colors , label : __( 'Foreground' ) } ) , 
                el( 'p' , null , __( 'Background' ) ) , 
                el( MetaColorPalette , { metaKey : 'backgroundColor' , useSlug : true , colors : colors , label : __( 'Background' ) } ) , 
            ); 
        }
    } );

} )( window.wp );

So, here's the thing: Everything is working quite fine, except the colors registered in editor-color-palette only show up when the block is re-rendered, e.g. by clicking somewhere in the editor and then switching back to the document settings.
The colors showing at the beginning are the 12 colors of 'fresh', I believe.
MetaColorPalette is one of a bunch of components I've added to store post_meta. At the beginning the console.log and the component shows (and saves) the default colors, not mine.
What am I missing?
Additionally, I tried using 'disable-custom-colors' in theme support with no result at all. Changing priority of the action containing add_theme_support does not change anything either.

If anyone needs the solution:
I localized the script:
wp_localize_script( 'colorsPanel' , 'wpColors' , [ 'palette' => get_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' )[0] ] );

